# Update table with different values from a different table which is grouped

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a oracle table called table1 that has a foreign key from table2.
table2 has 2 columns: id, name
table2.name has a lot of duplicates that need to be sorted out, so I grouped table2 by name and kept only 1 id for each name.
However, table1.table2_id uses a lot of the duplicated fields.

How can I change all the table1.table2_id fields so that there are no duplicate names?

Currently:
table1:

| id | blabla | table2_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | row | 1001 |
| 2 | row | 1002 |
| 3 | row | 1003 |
| 4 | row | 1004 |
| 5 | row | 1004 |
| 6 | row | 1005 |

table2:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | Bob |
| 1002 | Bob |
| 1003 | Bob |
| 1004 | Jack |
| 1005 | Jack |

Desired Result:
table1:

| id | blabla | table2_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | row | 1001 |
| 2 | row | 1001 |
| 3 | row | 1001 |
| 4 | row | 1004 |
| 5 | row | 1004 |
| 6 | row | 1004 |

table2:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | Bob |
| 1004 | Jack |

So imo, I would need to:

1. update all table1.table2_id to top 1 table2.id grouped by name
2. delete duplicate rows from table2

And as there are thousands of duplicate fields in table2, I cannot use case for this..

The solution I am trying returns 1 id for each name, but I am failing at the part where I can update the table.

```
update table1 d
set d.table2_id  = 
(select
b.id
from table2 b
where b.name in (select min(id) keep(dense_rank first order by id) id
     , name
  from table2
 group by name)
order by b.id ASC
)
where d.table2_id in ( SELECT b.id FROM table2 b WHERE b.name in (select min(id) keep(dense_rank first order by id) id
     , name
  from table2
 group by name));
```

Please help :)

Comment: Which dbms are you actually using?

Comment: Judging from the keep(...) structure, you are using Oracle. If so, pls only tag your question with Oracle, not with several random database products!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are syntactically correct Oracle statements

```
update table1 t1
set t1.table2_id = (
  select new_id
  from (
    select id, min(id) over (partition by name) new_id
    from table2
  ) d
  where d.id = t1.table2_id
);
```

```
delete from table2
where id not in (
  select min(id) from table2 group by name
);
```

The [analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056) `min(id) over (partition by name)` is used here so that you can have all original ids together with their new ids (the min ids from the set where the `name` is the same).

Answer (score 0):

here is one way:

```
update table1 d
set d.table2_id = x.id_tokeep
from 
(
select name , id , min(id) over (partition by name ) as id_tokeep
from table2
) x
 where x.id = d.table2_id

delete from table2
where id not in ( select min(id) from table2 group by name)
```